# Erro na hora de limpar e construir: "uses unchecked or unsafe operations."

Tags: java, array

Seguinte, tenho uma classe "Tabuleiro" no meu projeto que na hora de Limpar e Construir está apresentando o seguinte erro: "Tabuleiro.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations."

Dei uma pesquisada e a princípio seria problema de usar ArrayList genérico, sem definição de tipo. Porém os ArrayList da classe estão todos com definição de tipo :|

Segue a classe:

```
private void setItemCelula(){
    ArrayList<Pedra>[] listPedra = new ArrayList[linhas*colunas];
    ArrayList<Animal>[] listAnimal = new ArrayList[linhas*colunas];
    ArrayList<Arma>[] listArma = new ArrayList[linhas*colunas];
    ArrayList<Pessoa>[] listPessoa = new ArrayList[linhas*colunas];

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas*colunas; i++) {
        listPedra[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        listAnimal[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        listArma[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        listPessoa[i] = new ArrayList<>();       
    }

    for (Pedra pedra : this.itensTabuleiro.getPedras()) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pos = rand.nextInt(linhas*colunas);
        listPedra[pos].add(pedra);
    }
    for (Animal animal : this.itensTabuleiro.getAnimais()){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pos = rand.nextInt(linhas*colunas);
        if(listAnimal[pos].isEmpty())
            listAnimal[pos].add(animal);          
    }
    for (Arma arma : this.itensTabuleiro.getArmas()) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pos = rand.nextInt(linhas*colunas);
        listArma[pos].add(arma);
    }
    for (Pessoa pessoa : this.itensTabuleiro.getPessoas()) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pos = rand.nextInt(linhas*colunas);
        listPessoa[pos].add(pessoa);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (Celula[] linha : campos) {
        for (Celula coluna : linha) {
            Itens it = coluna.getItens();
            it.setPedras(listPedra[i]);
            it.setAnimais(listAnimal[i]);
            it.setArmas(listArma[i]);
            it.setPessoas(listPessoa[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para iniciarmos, isto não é um erro, é apenas um aviso. A causa raiz para este aviso é devido a [types erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), já que [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) é um [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

No seu código, na verdade, nenhuma destas declarações estão com definição de tipo:

```
ArrayList<Pedra>[] listPedra = new ArrayList[linhas * colunas];
ArrayList<Animal>[] listAnimal = new ArrayList[linhas * colunas];
ArrayList<Arma>[] listArma = new ArrayList[linhas * colunas];
ArrayList<Pessoa>[] listPessoa = new ArrayList[linhas * colunas];
```

Para evitar este aviso você tem algumas alternativas:

- "suprimir" o aviso, por exemplo adicionando isto ao seu método:

  ```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void setItemCelula() {}
  ```
- alterar sua solução de um vetor de [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) para lista de listas, pois em Java [não é possível criar array de tipos parametrizados](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays), algo assim:

  ```
  final List<List<Pedra>> listPedra = new ArrayList<>(linhas * colunas);
  final List<List<Animal>> listAnimal = new ArrayList<>(linhas * colunas);
  final List<List<Arma>> listArma = new ArrayList<>(linhas * colunas);
  final List<List<Pessoa>> listPessoa = new ArrayList<>(linhas * colunas);
  ```

Nesta segunda solução você precisará alterar a forma com que seu código está construído, levando em consideração que agora você não tem mais vetores, e sim listas de listas. Por exemplo, seu primeiro `for` ficaria assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linhas * colunas; i++) {
    listPedra.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
    listAnimal.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
    listArma.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
    listPessoa.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

E ao contrário de fazer isso:

```
listPedra[pos].add(pedra);
```

Você deve agora usar assim:

```
listPedra.get(pos).add(pedra);
```

P.S.: dê preferência para ter como referência uma interface, como a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) utilizada. Você consegue encontrar o porque desta boa prática facilmente na internet.